# In SAS how to rename variables in data?

Tags: sas

Status  Weight_Status   Smoking_status
High    Overweight  Moderate (6-15)
Normal  Overweight  Non-smoker
Optimal Overweight  Heavy (16-25)
High    Overweight  Non-smoker
Normal  Normal      Moderate (6-15)
Normal  Overweight  Non-smoker
Normal  Overweight  Very Heavy (> 25)

I want to rename weight_status variables from "overweight" to "aaa" and "Normal" to "bbb"

Answer (score 0):

You can read this to understand how make you need:

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000203026.htm